# Sending SM5100B messages using cutecom

Tags: raspberry-pi, gsm, at-command, hyperterminal

I would like to describe you what I did until now and what problem I have. My project is to connect the SM5100B GSM with a Raspberry Pi which runs Raspbian (similar version to debian) and to send message in my mobile. I did the first, the connection with the Raspberry pi. I have the cutecom as hyperterminal which I opened it, I connected the device /dev/ttyAMA0 and finally I clicked in the 'open device button'.
I have the following message:

```
+SIND: 4
```

I would like to send a message in my mobile. I wrote the following Inputs and I had the following results:

```
at
OK
at+cmgf=1
OK
at+cmgs="my number"
OK
>Hello
>Hello
```

But when I type or press ctrl-z it doesnt do anything. I have a spanish keyboard. What is the problem here? Is the problem the keyboard? Is the Cutecom's problem? Do I have to write any code?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an option to enter Hex input. Select this and send Ox1A1D0D.